# QML StackView Status.Inactive

Tags: qml, qt5, stackview

Does QML StackView `Status.Inactive`status mean that when a view enters this state it's visibility is set to false implicitly? So I don't need to set the view's visibility to false explicitly for performance reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could verify by adding the following to an item within the `StackView`:

```
onVisibleChanged: print(visible)
```

Looking at the [code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/StackView.qml), it seems that they are indeed hidden:

```
/*! \internal */
function animationFinished()
{
    if (!__currentTransition || __currentTransition.animation.running)
        return

    __currentTransition.animation.runningChanged.disconnect(animationFinished)
    __currentTransition.exitItem.visible = false
    __setStatus(__currentTransition.exitItem, Stack.Inactive);
    __setStatus(__currentTransition.enterItem, Stack.Active);
    __currentTransition.properties.animation = __currentTransition.animation
    root.delegate.transitionFinished(__currentTransition.properties)

    if (!__currentTransition.push || __currentTransition.replace)
        __cleanup(__currentTransition.outElement)

    __currentTransition = null
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mitch for confirming! The code piece says it all. Printing out the variable was a good idea too though, should have thought about that.